# Why are isolated zeros allowed in the weight function?

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-integral, quadrature

In an exercise I have determined the Gaussian Quadrature formula and I have applied that also for a specific function.

Then there is the following question:

Explain why isolated zeros are allowed in the weight function.

What exacly is meant by that? Could you explain that to me?

Comment: This is puzzling to me, because if they're talking about the usual setting of Gaussian quadrature, where you approximate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty w(x) f(x) dx$ by $\sum_{i=1}^n w_{i,n} f(x_{i,n})$ in the unique way which is exact for polynomials $f$ of degree $2n-1$, $w$ can have tons of zeros. (Consider Gauss-Legendre for example where $w$ is an indicator function of an interval.)

Comment: What exaxctly are isolated roots? @Ian

Comment: A zero is isolated if there is some interval containing it which contains no other zeros.

Comment: At this exercise I had determined the formula $$\int_{-1}^1f(x)\cdot \sqrt{|x|^3}\, dx\approx \sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\cdot w_i=f(x_1)\cdot w_1+f(x_2)\cdot w_2$$ So the weight function is $\sqrt{|x|^3}$ which has only the root $0$, right? Does this mean that $0$ is an isolated root? @Ian

Comment: $|x|^{3/2}$ has only an isolated zero, that is correct.

Comment: But why is that alllowed? @Ian

Comment: As I said, I don't even know why a whole interval of zeros is not being "allowed" in your reference. Gaussian quadrature doesn't really care if the support of $w$ is, say, a finite union of disjoint intervals.